# How do I print a message with a space separating each word?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in python that can take a message and use a Caesar cipher to encrypt the message, as well as brute force decrypt a message, for my tech class assignment. However when I encrypt or decrypt a message with multiple words like "Hello world!", the program returns the encrypted/decrypted message without any spaces or symbols e.g. "Hello world!" + shift 3 = "Khoorzruog".

This was the code that I used, have a gander and please let me know what I should do to fix it

```py
run = True

print("WELCOME TO THE C.C.E.D.P. (CAESAR CIPHER ENCRYPTION AND DECRYPTION PROGRAM)")
print("")

while run == True:
    def encrypt(message, shift):

        encryption = ""

        for character in message:
            if character.isupper():
                character_letter = ord(character) - ord("A")
                new_letter = (character_letter + shift) % 26
                new_unicode = new_letter + ord("A")
                new_character = chr(new_unicode)
                encryption = encryption + new_character
            elif character.islower():
                character_letter = ord(character) - ord("a")
                new_letter = (character_letter + shift) % 26
                new_unicode = new_letter + ord("a")
                new_character = chr(new_unicode)
                encryption = encryption + new_character
        return encryption

    print("ENTER [E] TO ENCRYPT A MESSAGE")
    print("ENTER [D] TO DECRPYT A MESSAGE")
    print("ENTER [Q] TO EXIT THE C.C.E.D.P.")
    eord = input("")

    encryption = ""

    if eord == "E":
        print("------------------------------")
        shift = int(input("ENTER SHIFT KEY: "))
        print("------------------------------")

        message = input("ENTER MESSAGE: ")

        print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("INSERTED TEXT:", message)
        print("------------------------------")
        print("ENCRYPTED TEXT:", encrypt(message, shift))
        print("------------------------------")

    elif eord == "D":
        print("------------------------------")
        str_in = input("ENTER MESSAGE: ")

        print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("POSSIBLE DECIPHERED MESSAGES. ")

        shift_counter = 27

        for shift in range(26):
            shift_counter -= 1
            str_out = ""
            str_out += encrypt(str_in, shift)
            print("------------------------------")
            print(shift_counter, str_out)

        print("------------------------------")

    elif eord == "Q":
        quit()

    elif eord == "e":
        print("------------------------------")
        shift = int(input("ENTER SHIFT KEY: "))
        print("------------------------------")

        message = input("ENTER MESSAGE: ")

        print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("INSERTED TEXT:", message)
        print("------------------------------")
        print("ENCRYPTED TEXT:", encrypt(message, shift))
        print("------------------------------")

    elif eord == "d":
        print("------------------------------")
        str_in = input("ENTER MESSAGE: ")

        print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("POSSIBLE DECIPHERED MESSAGES. ")

        shift_counter = 27

        for shift in range(26):
            shift_counter -= 1
            str_out = ""
            str_out += encrypt(str_in, shift)
            print("------------------------------")
            print(shift_counter, str_out)

        print("------------------------------")

    elif eord == "q":
        quit()
```

Comment: You are encoding the "space" character to "z".  The easy way to handle this is to add `if character == ' ':` to your `encrypt` routine to leave that character untouched.

Comment: One could say, it's not a bug, it's a feature. Having the encrypted text keeping whitespace makes it way easier to decrypt in mind I guess.

Comment: What do you think will happen if the message to be encrypted contains anything other than letters in the range A-Z, a-z or whitespace?

Comment: @TimRoberts Nope. `'w'` shift 3 becomes `'z'`. The op uses isupper() and islower(), of which space is neither, and so excludes spaces.

Comment: IDLE prints what Python sends to it, based on you code.  This should be the same for any IDE.  IDLE tag removed.

Answer (score 2):

For each character you are checking if it is uppercase using `character.isupper():` and then lowercase using `character.islower():` to decide how to encrypt. If neither of these conditions are true, no character is added to the encryption. You can test for yourself that the space character fails both  of these conditions.

```
character = ' '
assert character.islower() == False
assert character.isupper() == False
```

If you wanted to preserve spaces and special characters, you could extend your elif statements by lastly checking if the character is not a letter. In this case, you would append it to your new encrypted string as-is:

```
for character in message:
    if character.isupper():
        character_letter = ord(character) - ord("A")
        new_letter = (character_letter + shift) % 26
        new_unicode = new_letter + ord("A")
        new_character = chr(new_unicode)
        encryption = encryption + new_character
    elif character.islower():
        character_letter = ord(character) - ord("a")
        new_letter = (character_letter + shift) % 26
        new_unicode = new_letter + ord("a")
        new_character = chr(new_unicode)
        encryption = encryption + new_character
    elif not character.isalpha()
        encryption = encryption + character
return encryption
```

Note the above will preserve numbers as well.